# Remove <p>&nbsp;</p> with DOM or regex

Tags: php, html, regex, domparser

How can I remove this type p tag `<p>&nbsp;</p>` using DOM or regex?

I want to remove multiple p like this too,

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove a string that is exactly, always, `'<p>&nbsp;</p>'`, the simplest and fastest solution is probably to use [**`str_replace()`**](http://www.php.net/str_replace) :

```
$new_string = str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $old_string);
```

I don't think it's necessary to use DOM **for such a simple case** -- and a regex is not necessary here.

Of course, if you need to replace something more complex, that is not always exactly the same string... well, it'll be time for DOM manipulations ;-)

Comment: No regexp solutions are always faster

Comment: If the line is fixed, even an additional space will break it, even it will not modify output.

Comment: @WooDzu:regex faster than a simple str_replace() ? Not too sure about that.

Comment: @Cem Yes, if the string changes, this won't work anymore -- which is why I said "exactly, always" ;-)

Comment: @WooDzu oh, ok ^^ I understand better now, thanks for the precision :-) *(I was thinking you said "No, regex solution...")* ; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("|<p>&nbsp;</p>|", "", "<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to do that with xpath (your example is just demanding `str_replace` however), you can query the `&nbsp` entity as a string ([Demo](http://codepad.org/tqy7BGRL)):

```
$html = '<body><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Not empty :)</p>
</body>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$col = $xpath->query("//p[text()=\"\xC2\xA0\"]"); # &nbsp;
foreach($col as $e) {
    $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
```

Hope this is helpful if you need to query `&nbsp;` with xpath.

See as well: [Using XPATH to search text containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing)