# Possible to search for XML elements by a sub-element's text value in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I have an XML file with a structure like this:

```
<index>
    <compound kind="file">
        <name>file.c</name>
        <member kind="variable"><name>foo</name></member>
        <member kind="variable"><name>bar</name></member>
        ...
    </compound>
    <compound kind="file">
        <name>file.h></name>
        <member>...
    </compound>
</index>
```

I need to search by file member name but I can't figure out if there is a way that avoids iterating the entire tree. My solution currently looks like:

```
for f in xmlroot.iter("compound"):
    for m in f.iter("member"):
        if m.find("name").text == my_var_name:
            print "Found"
```

Is there a way to use a dict() search to improve efficiency because I actually have another for loop above that that goes through the list of variables to search for so performance-wise this is really poor.

Would changing those two for loops to a single XPath search improve performance?

Comment: Couldn't you just parse the whole xml once and store the data in, say, a dictionary. The Dictionary could be of the form {'member_name':[files_in_which_it_occurs]. This assumes different files can have same member names.

Comment: This is answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing#247903

Comment: @RedBaron: yes, that's possible, just feels a bit silly since lxlm already has dictionaries.

Comment: @Mikko: I don't understand how that answer applies here.

Comment: lxml provides API to use XPath selectors. You can select the nodes by content by using the XPath expression with XPath text() function.