# XPath works on Chrome console but not on Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

**@Arran solved, selenium dont work well with

 text() function, updated xpath to ://table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a**

I need manipulate a internal system and it never get on time.
I changed timeouts to load and script to 30 hours to see its really a time problem.
I disabled javascript.
Nothing worked.
I created a very minimal version of my Selenium code and a minimal plain html file version that i put on my webserver.
When i open on Chrome and type $x('//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a/text()') on console the xpath get what i want.
But when i do the same on PhantomJSDriver there is a neverendig process ( i know the timeout is set to 30 hours)
When i compare by Fiddler the content is the same.
I dont need GPU here but when i try the ChromeDriver its throw an exeption related with gpu:
    [4588:4592:0519/143844:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(140)] Could not read gaming score from assessment results.

The minimal html is:

```
<html>  
 <head>
    <title>Its a test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table width=200>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href='http://uej65ge.com/lnk001.html'>text01</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='http://uej65ge.com/lnk002.html'>text02</a>
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href='http://uej65ge.com/lnk003.html'>text03</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='http://uej65ge.com/lnk004.html'>text04</a>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

The WebDriver code is:
//-------------------------------------------------

```
public void start() throws FileNotFoundException {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = getPhanthomDriver();
        scrapTest(driver);
    }
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
private WebDriver getPhanthomDriver() {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();                        
            String pathToPhantom = ConfigProvider.getStringConfig("pathToPhantom");                    
            caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, pathToPhantom);
            caps.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ConsoleHelper.printMessage("ERRO_io:" + ex.getMessage(), new Date());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ConsoleHelper.printMessage("ERRO_ex:" + ex.getMessage(), new Date());
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
private WebDriver getChromeDriver() {
        // [4588:4592:0519/143844:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(140)] Could not read gaming score from assessment results.
        // I dont need GPU here !!!
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {            
            String pathToChrome = ConfigProvider.getStringConfig("pathToChrome");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToChrome);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ConsoleHelper.printMessage("ERRO_ex:" + ex.getMessage(), new Date());
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
public void scrapTest(WebDriver driver) throws FileNotFoundException {        
        // this its form more than 05 minutes without return
        try {
            long pollingForSecond = 1;
            long timeOutInSeconds = 999999;
            if(driver == null){ throw new Exception("Erro, driver informado era nulo");}
            String initialUrl = "http://devw7lng:8080/CPS/xpts.html";
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            driver.get(initialUrl);
            final String xpath_categoriasTexto = "'//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a/text()'";
            List<WebElement> elements = null;
            try {

                Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                        .withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .pollingEvery(pollingForSecond, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                        .ignoring(org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException.class);
                elements = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        System.out.print(".");
                        return driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath_categoriasTexto));
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception err) {
            }
            boolean ok = false;
            ok = ((elements != null) && (elements.size() > 0));
            int x = 0;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ConsoleHelper.printMessage("ERRO_ex:" + ex.getMessage(), new Date());
        }
    }
```

//-------------------------------------------------

Comment: There is someone using text() function with selenium here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure of the reason it is sitting there for a while but nonetheless, I wouldn't use what you are using.

`//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a/text()` is not going to give you actual `WebElement`'s therefore, I'd take a different approach:

`//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a` and then call `.getText()` on all the elements it finds - the `.getText()` method is there for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help and attention.  
Really the text() function dont work, with your help i found another problems.  

{***** the xpath was enclosed on apostrophes not only on quotation marks}  

{*****its dont work, i get on neverending wait:  
"//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a/text()"}  

{*****searching about text() function on selenium i found it but using it i need to call gettext on same way, there is no advantage:    
"//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a[text()]"}  

{*****using your suggestion and it working fast now:
"//table[@width=200]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a"}