# How to assert text content in unknown node in SoapUI

Tags: xquery, soapui, assert

I have a webService that returns certain values.

```
<BasicPersons>
           <id>4</id>
           <firstName>Patricia</firstName>
           <middleName>A</middleName>
           <lastName>Cluss</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
           <id>5</id>
           <firstName>Benjamin</firstName>
           <middleName>L</middleName>
           <lastName>Handen</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
           <id>6</id>
           <firstName>Ellen</firstName>
           <lastName>Frank</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
```

I know what some of those values will be but **i don't know the order of the nodes**. I want to assert that one of the "basicPersons" node contain firstname=Benjamin. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the order of nodes, just `*/BasicPersons[firstName='Benjamin']` -- it searches every child of `basicPerson` where text is exactly Benjamin.

upd: some helpful link [Using XPATH to search text containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing)

upd2: thank you guys for editing, I've missed `firstname` tag

Comment: i know that, but what assert should i use in soapui

Comment: Add assertion to the request -> Property Content -> XPath match (http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html) or if need some additional actions use Script Assertion (http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/script-assertions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XPath assertion like:

```
exists(//*:BasicPersons[contains(*:firstName, 'Benjamin')])
```