# Xpath how to check title value if value is extended character

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

this is HTML that I want to find

```
<a href="/audio-books/type/computer/page/2/">»</a>
```

problem is » what is

```
&raquo;
```

I have tried:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="wp-pagenavi"]/a[@title="»"]' )
```

and

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="wp-pagenavi"]/a[@title="&raquo;"]' )
```

but it is not working.

**Is there some way to check for a value in XPath if the value is from character entities or extended characters?**

I am trying to find lin to next page so I can to use

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="wp-pagenavi"]/a[@title="2"]' )
```

and this is working fine.

Comment: While not what you asked, by far the less painful and more accurate selector would use the URI in the `href` rather than what is essentially a presentation issue looking for the guillemet; so: `//a[contains(@href, "/page/")]/@href` (assuming you wanted the actual `href`; omit that `/@href` to just get the target `a` tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your path is incorrect because you are using `title` attribute to match, which is incorrect, the character is inside `text()` not `title`. This xpath should work:

```
response.xpath(u'//a[./text()="\xbb"]')
```

Comment: Foremost, thank you for clarifying that it is the `text()` one should match, not `@title` that was used everywhere else in this question. As a tiny bit of pedantry, one need not qualify the `text()` with `./` as it is implied to be the `a` by the use of the array-brackets. To be extra cautious, one could say `a[string(.)="\xbb"]` to side-step if they wrap the guillemet in a `<span>` or such in the future (whitespace concerns aside, cause I have finite characters here :-))

Comment: @eLRuLL thank you. I have not even noticed that this HTML tag does not have a title, the problem was because other ones had.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to run it but you should use the decimal entity for finding the extended characters via `XPath`.

For `&raquo;` you should use `&#187;`, you `XPath` should be like

```
div[@class="wp-pagenavi"]/a[@title="&#187;"]'
```

see the complete chart [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_r.asp) for the reference.

If it does not work you can go for the [Unicode character for `&raquo;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bb/index.htm), Additionally you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-nbsp), hope this helps you out.

Comment: not working, I have a feeling that this also depend on Xpath implementation in scrapy framework