# How to write locator for text between div and span (Preferably xpath) which contains non-breaking space (&nbsp)

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to write **xpath** for the following div:

```
<div class='someclass' id='someid'>:TEST&nbsp;SELENIUM&nbsp;1234<div>
```

Please note :

1. **tag** can be anything such as div, span ,or anchor tag.
2. `&nbsp;` can be present anywhere in the text.

What I have **tried** so far :

```
//div[contains(text(),":TEST SELENIUM 1234")]

//div[contains(text(),":TEST{&nbsp;}SELENIUM{&nbsp;}1234")] 

//div[contains(text(),":TEST&nbsp;SELENIUM&nbsp;1234")] 

//div[normalize-space(text()) = ':TEST SELENIUM 1234']

//div[normalize-space(text()) = ':TEST{&nbsp;}SELENIUM{&nbsp;}1234']

//div[normalize-space(text()) = ':TEST&nbsp;SELENIUM&nbsp;1234']

//div[normalize-space(.) = ':TEST SELENIUM 1234']  

//div[normalize-space(.) = ':TEST{&nbsp;}SELENIUM{&nbsp;}1234']  

//div[normalize-space(.) = ':TEST&nbsp;SELENIUM&nbsp;1234']  

//div[normalize-space(.) = ':TEST{\u00a0}SELENIUM{\u00a0}1234']  

//div[normalize-space(.) = ':TEST${nbsp}SELENIUM${nbsp}1234']
```

What has worked for me (thanks to @Andersson)

```
//div[starts-with(text(), ":TEST") and substring(text(), 7)="SELENIUM" and  substring(text(), 16)="1234"]
```

This is more of a work around and would work only for known Strings.

These are the SO post which I have already followed :

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-nbsp)
[Link2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/how-to-indicate-an-nbsp-in-xpath)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you testing this? Is it `xPath 2.0`, right? In Chrome and Firefox it is not working

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : I want to click on check boxes based on names. Names can be extracted only form the divs. Yes I'm using `xpath2.0` .No , it's not working in FF and chrome. If you know any workaround , that'd be really helpful.

Comment: Why don't you use `//div[starts-with(text(), ":TEST") and contains(text(), "SELENIUM")]`? This will return all divs which has both text irrespective of spaces between them. and you can add more `and` condition as needed.

Comment: If you want to make it generic instead of dev, use this code: `//*[starts-with(text(), ":TEST") and contains(text(), "SELENIUM")]`

Comment: Instead of `starts-with`, you can use simply `contains` too. E.g. `//*[contains(text(), ":TEST") and contains(text(), "SELENIUM")]`

Comment: And this works on chrome.

Comment: @RajKamal `starts-with` is better

Comment: @RajKamal : The text is not generic , it can be `xyz&nbsp1234` also

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Yes! I just gave a suggestion, in case , if we need to use multiple `contains`, we can do so.

Comment: @cruisepandey If text is not generic , what you want to validate?? I assumed that you are looking for an element with some text?

Comment: whatever text is, you can pass that text to create xpath at runtime.. That's what I mean.

Comment: @RajKamal : Yes. I am reading text from excel file and creating an item in UI. That  particular text can be anything , as I do not have control over it.

Comment: But you know the text what you are passing in excel will be used to create element. Use same text to create xpath at runtime.

Comment: your solution `//*[contains(text(), ":TEST") and contains(text(), "SELENIUM")]` will be good but if I have 3-4 sub strings then it wouldn't work I guess

Comment: For your case, xpath string will have to be designed at runtime, depending on how many `contains` condition, you need.

Comment: @RajKamal : Yes , can you give the generic solution, that'd really helpful.

Comment: @RajKamal : I mean how can we have multiple contains as per the requirement while designing the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

According to the conversation above, you can use this sample `xPath` builder(JAVA):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = ":TEST&nbsp;SELENIUM&nbsp;1234";
        String[] parts = s.split("&nbsp;");
        StringBuilder xpath = new StringBuilder("//*");

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            xpath.append((i == 0) ? "[contains(text(), '" + parts[i] + "')" : " and contains(text(), '" + parts[i] + "')");
        }
        xpath.append("]");

        System.out.println(xpath);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
//*[contains(text(), ':TEST') and contains(text(), 'SELENIUM') and contains(text(), '1234')]
```

Comment: It looks quite complex , let me give a try. this might take some times. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @cruisepandey I am pretty sure, there is a space to optimize this code. It is just quick and dirty example ;)

Comment: @RajKamal : If you have any better solution or can optimize the same code ,that'd be really appreciated.

Comment: @cruisepandey I have edited my answer, a little bit optimized the code and fixed some bugs. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

In Python I would do

```
required_div = [div for div in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div') if div.text == ':TEST SELENIUM 1234'][0]
```

to find required node by its complete text content ignoring non-breaking space chars

P.S. Again it's just a workaround, but it seem to be quite simple solution