# How to find an element which contains &nbsp; using Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework, xpath-1.0

```
<td>By Company&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

I need to capture xpath of the above element. I tried following alternatives, but nothing seems to be working in chrome. Can you please suggest any other option.

```
"//td[normalize-space(text())='By Company\u00a0']"
"//td[normalize-space(text())='By Company\u00a0\u00a0']"
"//td[text()='By Company\u00a0']"
"//td[text()[normalize-space(.)='By Company\u00a0']]"
"//td[text()[normalize-space()='By Company\u00a0']]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To locate the element:

```
<td>By Company&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

You can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

- Using `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  "//td[contains(normalize-space(translate(., '\u00A0\u00A0', ' ')), 'By Company')]"
  ```
- Using `text()`:

  ```
  "//td[text()='By Company\u00A0\u00A0']"
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  "//td[contains(., 'By Company\u00A0\u00A0')]"
  ```

---

However, ideally you may like to avoid the *NO-BREAK SPACE* character and use either of the following solutions:

- Using `starts-with()`:

  ```
  "//td[starts-with(., 'By Company')]"
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  "//td[contains(., 'By Company')]"
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Using XPATH to search text containing `&nbsp;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-nbsp/59699055#59699055)

---

### tl; dr

[Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Ignore it, locate by "By Company" only

```
//td[contains(., 'By Company')]
```