# Python Selenium: Find Element by XPath, &nbsp; issue

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, normalization, xpath-1.0

Could you please help me with the following issue:

I am trying to identify various elements on webpages via their XPath by using the Selenium Diver. Although I have already read some Questions on this, I do not manage to solve my issue with  "*& nbsp;*".

This is the **elements' text** according to the Webpage-Code, which I am using to find the element:

```
DISCUSSION&nbsp;AND ANALYSIS
```

This is **my X-Path**, which does not work so far (I am receiving an error message):

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(normalize-space(translate(//data, '&#160;', ' '))), 'DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS')]")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed

```
//*[contains(normalize-space(translate(//data, '&#160;', ' '))), 'DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS')]
```

would work if you replaced `//data` by `.`. The `//data` here makes no sense at all.

You might also want to use an "=" test rather than a "contains" test, and to use `//data` instead of `//*` at the start -- but that all depends on what else might be present in the document to cause a false match.

Translating NBSP to SP really isn't necessary; you can just include a NBSP in the string you are testing against. But again, it depends on what possible variations you think might arise in the test document.

Comment: I did little adjustments and thanks to your comment finally made it work! TY! 

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(normalize-space(translate(., '\u00A0', ' ')), 'DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS')]")

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to remove   from your xpath expression

Use this xpath

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'DISCUSSION')]")
```

or

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'AND ANALYSIS')]")
```

Comment: Thanks, I would love to use this approach! However, I need the "entire" expression "DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS" to identify my target elements to avoid excessive findings.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The element text being:

```
DISCUSSION&nbsp;AND ANALYSIS
```

To locate the element through it's text you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  "//*[text()='DISCUSSION\u00A0AND ANALYSIS']"
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  "//*[contains(., 'DISCUSSION\u00A0AND ANALYSIS')]"
  ```

---

However, ideally you may like to avoid the *NO-BREAK SPACE* character and use either of the following solutions:

- Using `starts-with()`:

  ```
  "//*[starts-with(., 'DISCUSSION')]"
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  "//*[contains(., 'AND ANALYSIS')]"
  ```
- Using `starts-with()` and `contains()`:

  ```
  "//*[starts-with(., 'DISCUSSION') and contains(., 'AND ANALYSIS')]"
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find an element which contains   using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624749/how-to-find-an-element-which-contains-nbsp-using-selenium/59625175#59625175)
- [Using XPATH to search text containing `&nbsp;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-nbsp/59699055#59699055)

---

### tl; dr

[Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)