# How to write xpath for an element containing '&nbsp' and svg tag in between?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath, webdynpro

I am trying to get the xpath of the highlighted element(span) in the below image.
[image]

I tried the below options and none of them are working:

```
 //span[contains(text(),'Database')]
 //span[ends-with(., 'Database')]
 //span[text()='\u00A0\u00A0Database']
 //span[contains(., '\u00A0\u00A0Database')]
```

Comment: can you please mention the URL if it's public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

The desired text *`&nbsp;Database`* is within the `<span>`.

---

### Solution

To locate the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH* and the text *Database`*:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'Database')]
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the text *`&nbsp;Database`*:

  ```
  //span[contains(., '\u00A0Database')]
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find an element which contains   using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625175/7429447)
- [Using XPATH to search text containing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59699055/7429447)

Comment: Thank you :)
It worked with the first approach!! [//span[contains(., 'Database')]]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to find the highlighted `span` tag with its `id` attribute using XPATH as below:

```py
//span[@id="WD4B-cnt-start"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But unfortunately, this solution will not work since the id is dynamic.