# Xpath doesn't detect text with nbsp

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<tr>
 <td align="left" width="200">
  <p>Document Uploaded:&nbsp;Yes</p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I'm unable to locate the element with `&nbsp;` in the text. The below XPath expression does not not work and I've tried so many other suggestions online but have not been successful yet. FYI: I need the entire text not just a substring of it.

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Document Uploaded: Yes')]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using XPATH to search text containing &nbsp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247135/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-nbsp)

Comment: I tried that as well and it did not work @AlexRudenko

Comment: try //*[translate(.,'\u00A0',' ')='Document Uploaded: Yes']

Comment: Have you provided the complete XML document or just a fragment of it? Please, provide a complete, but minimal in length document that still exhibits the reported problem. I suspect that the failure to select the wanted element may be due to namespace issues.

Comment: Can you, please explain what do you mean by this: "FYI: I need the entire text not just a snippet of it."? The provided XPath expression selects one (in your case) or more `<p>` elements, not text-nodes. Also, if you are specifying in the predicate the string `"'Document Uploaded: Yes'"`, then you already know "the entire text"... So what do you actually mean by that? Very confused!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Document Uploaded:&#160;Yes')]
```

`&#160;` is the *Numeric character reference* for the *Named character reference* `&nbsp;` (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings)). It can also be used in a DOCTYPE declaration at the beginning of an XML/XSLT document to make `&nbsp;` usuable:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp  "&#160;" >
]>
```

Comment: I guess the handling depends on the XPath-Parser. I tested it with `xsltproc` and `Saxon9`, and there it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//p[. = 'Document Uploaded:&#xA0;Yes']
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

This XSLT transformation just evaluates the above XPath expression and outputs the result of the evaluation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "//p[. = 'Document Uploaded:&#xA0;Yes']"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp  "&#160;" >
]>
<tr>
 <td align="left" width="200">
  <p>Document Uploaded:&nbsp;Yes</p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>Document Uploaded: Yes</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd one this! The other answers mentioned above should word.

An alternative solution is to work around the character:

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Document Uploaded:')][contains(text(), 'Yes')]
```

Use an xpath that looks for an element that contains both string you need. If you need it to be more rigid, you can use `starts-with` and `ends-with`.

Another approach is don't find this item by text but rather get the element and process it in Java.
I can't give a working example as I would need to see more html but the process would be:

- Find an fixed anchor point e.g. something else in your html table you can identify easily
- Create an xpath from that anchor with `following-sibling::` or `parent::` or `following::` (you get the idea) - whatever to find this `Document Uploaded:` element
- set that as your xpath in java with `findElement`.
- In java: `myElement.getText()`

I think Selenium is smart enough to strip out the `nbsp` character - but even if it does not you'll still have a text string confirming your document upload status.